# Use of $installer v $this in install scripts

Tags: magento-1, installation, resource-model, setup-script, install-script

Ok, using install scripts there seems to be a weird convention to use the following:

```
$installer = $this;
```

I really don't understand this as it is completely redundant.

Why not just use `$this->` throughout the script?

Any ideas on why this convention exists?

Comment: I get warnings about this being used outside object context in vscode. Any idea how I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is much simpler. In 2007 (and I believe till 2009 when PhpStorm started rocking) no one IDE allowed to provide inline phpdoc for `$this`. But core developers wanted to have autocompletion in IDE. That's why they used these 2 lines:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer <appropriate class> */
```

Some modules have own setup class and it should have been used in inline phpdoc. But because setup/upgrade script were (and are) always created via "copy/paste some existing one and change" you can find maybe examples when module has own setup class (or uses eav setup model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`) but `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` is used in inline phpdoc in upgrade script.

Answer (score 8):

The oldest version I have is 1.0. Even then `$installer = $this;` existed. Even in the files named `upgrade-0.x.y-0.z.t` this line exists.

In my opinion, when they started (I mean version 0.1 or something like that) they had something like `$installer = new Something()` and they decided to change the logic.
I assume this because of the `<class>` tag in the `config.xml` of some modules (Mage_Catalog for example).
Versions before 1.6:

```
<setup>
    <module>Mage_Catalog</module>
    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
</setup>
```

Or in versions 1.6+ :

```
<setup>
    <module>Mage_Catalog</module>
    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
</setup>
```

I usually use `$this` instead of `$installer` and I didn't have any issue (if that maters in any way).

Answer (score 7):

This is a convention of unknown and possibly dubious logic present since the earliest public beta from 2007 ([Preview B1 0.6.12383](http://www.magentocommerce.com/getmagento/0.6.12383/Magento-B1Preview-0.6.tar.gz); login required).

It is used as a convention to ensure that the class which is executing setup code is consistently aliased in setup scripts. For example, while both the `Enterprise_GiftWrapping` and `Enterprise_Rma` modules have their own setup classes, they each alias `$installer` to an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` when adding attributes to the product entity, e.g.:

**app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftWrapping/sql/enterprise_giftwrapping_setup/install-1.11.0.0.php**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Model_Resource_Setup */
//... miscellaneous Enterprise_GiftWrapping setup logic

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
//... miscellaneous product entity attribute manipulation
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing I like about using `$installer` that I really want to add is that it makes it easy to replace it with something else or to run it outside of the class scope.

**1. Replacing it:**

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
// Do basic stuff

$installer = Mage::getSingleton('eav/entity_setup', 'eav_setup');
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
/// Do stuff with attributes
```

**2. Outside scope:**

```
$ php -a
php > require_once 'app/Mage.php';
php > Mage::init();
php > require 'app/code/local/Vendor/Module/data/vendormodule_setup/data-upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php';
Upgrade worked!
Debug data dump: array(4) {
  'id' =>
  int(123)
  'foo' =>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Of course with `data-upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php` having:

```
//$installer = $this;
$installer = Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/setup', 'vendormodule_setup');
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

// Do lots of stuff ...

echo "Upgrade worked!\n";
echo "Debug data dump: ";
var_dump($debug);
```

So this prevents `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: $installer = Mage::getSingleton('eav/entity_setup', 'eav_setup'); is important to remember... You are not limited to just Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup'...

Answer (score 3):

I would guess it is from earlier days (<v.1.1). But to be honest, I have no idea. I think it is a bit better readable...

> We have always done it like this

You know ;-)

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense in any PHP OOP code, but used it initially too. Then at some point ignored that part completely, and never had any issue. So my experience is that you can safely ignore this code.

Comment: Yea, I think so too. I'm just used to it...